# How do you update Openshift NodeJS Cartridge's Express from 3.x to the latest 4.x?

Tags: node.js, express, openshift

When Openshift creates a Node.js cartridge it includes a version of Express 3. My app is an Express 4 app and fails to start under the default Openshift setup. Even if my app's package.json has the line "express": ">=4.9.0" in dependencies.

4.9.0 happens to be the version that is embedded in my app's project but is ignored by Openshift when started there. So apparently I need to update Openshift's version to 4. I can confirm that the app works as designed and intended on my local computer.

How do I update Openshift's Express, which is outside the app, from version 3 to 4 ?

Comment: https://github.com/wshearn/openshift-origin-cartridge-nodejs says:"To deploy this cartridge with the cartridge reflector you can execute the following command `rhc create-app <app name> "http://cartreflect-claytondev.rhcloud.com/reflect?github=wshearn/openshift-origin-cartridge-nodejs`" -- That didn't work?

Comment: @robert-harvey, I'm not sure how to use this. It is not clear from reading the Readme how it is addressing my need.  I am looking for guidance in updating/upgrading Openshift's Express 3 to Express 4.

Comment: And a deployment of the latest software will not accomplish that?  That's usually how these things work.

Answer (score 0):

I made sure that my /package.json includes something like this under dependencies:

```
"express": "~4.11.1"
```

Personally, I retired my /bin/www content by removing that out of /package.json:

```
...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "main": "server.js"
}
```

...and migrated much of /bin/www back into /server.js.

That seemed to be the only way I could get Express4 to work on OpenShift.

1. /server.js needs a shebang a the top "#!/bin/env node"
2. /package.json gets the mod above

I've got my Express4 app running now with MongoDB support.  Seems to be happy.  Pushes/builds/logs success.

Comment: I was eventually able to determine that in fact though Openshift had set up the Cartridge using Express 3, my app was actually using the Express 4 that was part of my project. I just tweeked endlessly and unfortunately do not have a definitive path that made it eventually work, but it does.  I am still using /bin/www so that I can start the app with the  npm start  command.

Comment: You're a better geek than I am, Ric.  I spent a fair amount of time trying to get bin/www to own the application space but kept running into problems.

Answer (score 0):

Which works for me is:

```
"main": "./bin/www",
"scripts": {
  "start": "node ./bin/www"
}
```